# Do-while question java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

My program will provide information on buildings, which is stored in an online Oracle database. I got it to ask the user to enter the building number and then run and display the results of several queries.

Here is what I got so far:

```
String userbnumber = null;
try {
    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Please enter the building number: "); 
    userbnumber = obj.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {   
}
// A Lot of queries which use userbnumber as the basis for getting data from tables
```

However, what I can't figure out is how /where to use the do-while clause to keep asking for the building number until the user enters 0 at which point the program would print "Thank you for your time" and stop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 do {
     try {
         System.out.print("Please enter the building number: "); 
         userbnumber = obj.readLine();
         if(!usernumber.equals("0"){
         //perform action here
         }
     } catch (IOException e) { 
         //handle it
     }
 } while(!userbnumber.equals("0"));
```

better way is to

```
while(true){
        try {
             System.out.print("Please enter the building number: "); 
             userbnumber = obj.readLine();
             if(usernumber.equals("0"){
                     break;
             }
             //perform action here
         } catch (IOException e) { 
             //handle it
         }

}
```

Comment: You might want to check for non-zero input before performing the action. Which is why I believe in `read(); while() { // action }` instead.

Comment: @marcog yes also suggested another way

Comment: It rather looks like you are going to go around the loop even if there is an `IOException`.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline `//handle it `

Comment: @org.life.java Oh my compiler ignores that. And most programmers seem to think that a `printf`-equivalent (which don't [often] throw) is really pushing the boat out.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline *OK* @user551163 See the above comment and decide it your self

Answer (score 1):

```
package pack34;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Letstryagain34 {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    String userbnumber = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Please enter the building number: "); 
        userbnumber = obj.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
             // handle it!
        }
        /*A Lot of queries which use userbnumber as the basis for getting data from tables
        */      
do{
/* Fetch the Question from Database & write back the answer here*/

        System.out.print("Want to continue :  "); 
int choice = obj.readLine();
}while(choice!=0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package pack34;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Letstryagain34 {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    String userbnumber = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do{
            System.out.print("Please enter the building number: "); 
            userbnumber = obj.readLine();
        }while(!"0".equals(userbnumber))
            System.out.println("Thank you for your time");
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            System.out.println("Argh! Nasty error..");
        }
        /*A Lot of queries which use userbnumber as the basis for getting data from tables
        */      
    }
}
```